# Getting MethodTable for Arrays

Tags: c#, .net, pointers

I am trying to get Methodtable for array instances, i.e int[], long[] etc.
I can get MerthodTable without any problems for any other classes except arrays.

Here is the code I use to get method table pointer and how I make sure it works

```
 private static unsafe int* GetMethodtable<T>(T obj) {
    var referenceForObject= __makeref(obj);
    return (int*)(*(int*)*((int*)&referenceForObject));
 }

var instance = new MyClass();
var methodtableAddress = (int*)*GetMethodtable(instance);
var @equals = (int*)typeof(MyClass).TypeHandle.Value == methodTableAddress;
```

In the above code `@equals` is `true` for any other class except array types.
My question is how to get the methodTableAddress for array types using the pointer to the object?